# Dynamic include of a list of variables into a Jquery function as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

How to dynamically inject a list of variables into a function if neither name nor number of variables is known in advance. In particular:

I am trying to replace this "hardcoded" version:

`$.when(img1Loaded,img2Loaded,img3Loaded).done(function () { ... etc`

with something like this:

`$.when(MyDynamicList).done(function () { ... etc`

In a broader context, var MyDynamicList could be populated with a script and it holds a response from a function announcing load completion of each image. That is, I need to reference a number of such variables declared as follows:

`var img1Loaded = $.Deferred();`

and then referenced in 'img.onload' function as: `img1Loaded.resolve();`

I have it all working for a single image but not for 2 or more...

By analogy:

```
var it=['#d1,#d2'];

$(it[0]).on( "click", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

In other words, how to create equivalent of 'it' for my case. This is totally wrong:  `var MyDynamicList= img1Loaded,.... imgNLoaded;`

I drew a total blank on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could create your own "when" function that handles arrays using promises:

```
function myWhen(dynamicList) {        
    const promises = dynamicList.map(item => new Promise( function(resolve,reject) {
        $.when(item).done(data => resolve(data));
    } ) );

    return Promise.all(promises);
}

const MyDynamicList = [$.ajax( "foo" ) , $.ajax( "bar.aspx" ) ...];

myWhen(MyDynamicList).then( items => {
    //do stuff
} ).catch(err => {
    //handle error
})
```

myWhen shall complete when all the "thenables" in dynamicList resolve.

You can read more about promises here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Hope this helps

Comment: Check the latest version of the answer, i realised I made a tiny mistake

Comment: Your suggested approach works as anticipated, thanks Martin! If there are no other suggestions I will redefine my approach and accept your answer as a final solution.

Comment: great. no further suggestions for now

Comment: This is actually a very handy piece of code for many different scenarios. Thanks for sharing Martin!